# Unsatisfiable error while installing tensorflow-gpu in Anaconda

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I have installed Anaconda Python 3.7 in Ubuntu 18.04 and then executed the commands:

```
conda update --all
conda install cudnn
```

Now when I try to install tensorflow-gpu using the command `conda install tensorflow-gpu`, I get Unsatisfiable error like this:

> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be
>   incompatible with each other:
>
> - pkgs/main/linux-64::_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf==0.1.0=py37_0 -> ipywidgets -> widgetsnbextension[version='>=3.4.0,<3.5.0'] ->
>     notebook[version='>=4.4.1'] -> nbconvert -> bleach
> - pkgs/main/linux-64::bleach==3.1.0=py37_0
> - pkgs/main/linux-64::ipywidgets==7.4.2=py37_0 -> widgetsnbextension[version='>=3.4.0,<3.5.0'] ->
>     notebook[version='>=4.4.1'] -> nbconvert -> bleach
> - pkgs/main/linux-64::jupyterlab==0.35.5=py37hf63ae98_0 -> jupyterlab_server[version='>=0.2.0,<0.3.0'] -> notebook -> nbconvert
>     -> bleach
> - pkgs/main/linux-64::jupyterlab_server==0.2.0=py37_0 -> notebook -> nbconvert -> bleach
> - pkgs/main/linux-64::notebook==5.7.8=py37_0 -> nbconvert -> bleach
> - pkgs/main/linux-64::widgetsnbextension==3.4.2=py37_0 -> notebook[version='>=4.4.1'] -> nbconvert -> bleach
> - pkgs/main/noarch::nbconvert==5.5.0=py_0 -> bleach

As multiple important packages are concerned here, I am getting confused what to do. I have NVIDIA GTX 1070 Max-Q in my PC, so tensorflow-gpu should work perfectly.

Comment: Hi Preetom, Is the issue resolved now? Else, Can you confirm if it is working with Python Version 3.6?

Answer (score 0):

You can install Tensorflow GPU using the below code:

1. Create a New Virtual Environment

   `conda create -n tensorflow_gpu pip python=3.6`
2. Activate the Virtual Environment

   `activate tensorflow_gpu`
3. Install CUDA Toolkit using

   `conda install -c anaconda cudatoolkit`
4. Install Tensorflow GPU

   `pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu==1.15`

For more information, please refer this [Tensorflow Blog](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#tensorflow-gpu).

Comment: Yes, my version was too high too. Had 3.9.

Comment: Yeah! Till 1.12 version, Python Max_version was 3.6 , Now Python 3.7 is max version for 1.15 . [Ref](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#tested_build_configurations)